# Cannot allocate heap space when 80% of RAM free (ec2 Windows image)

Tags: java, windows, amazon-web-services, heap-memory, allocation

we have a Windows 2012 SP2 on an EC2 instance with 64GB. We are running around 8 Java applications and a lot of other non-Java applications as well. Task manager shows that 22% of the memory is used. We try to start Java applications with Xmx128M or even lower and we get "Cannot allocate heap space". How can that be?

I know that 22% may not represent the reality. It may be that more space has been allocated for (Java) applications... but still there is plenty of space free! And other non-java applications do start. Could that be a problem related to the way AWS EC2 instances distribute memory to the jvm? The jdk 8 installed is 64bit, although somebody had incorrectly installed a 32bit jdk at the beginning- now removed. Could it be, that some of the old 32bit configurations (maybe in the registry) are interfering?

This is a very weird case... Any help or assumptions are appreciated

Comment: What are your Xmx settings and what type of jvm server class/non-server class? and note that though have 64GB, by default it won't be allocated all to JVM, here are default details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size

Comment: Do note that the amount of physical memory has little to do with whether memory allocations can succeed or not.

Comment: On my Windows 7 machine, my 32-bit jdk1.8.0_91 can run with `-Xmx` values between `1m` and `1351m`. My 64-bit version can run with values between `1m` and `657g`. Of course, since I only have 32g and no pagefile, it'll die before actually *using* that much, but the JVM starts without problems. Anyway, a value of `128M` shouldn't be a problem. Do you perhaps specify other options that may cause a conflict?

Comment: We always run -server. My Xmx settings vary. Sometimes i set Xmx1M and it doesn't work! I do "java -Xmx1M" and it still cannot allocate heap space